# blank green screen in Preview

Tags: macos

If I open a large .JPG file in Preview I will see a big blank green screen...

[image: Result]

I tried to delete the user's cache, some files from the preferences, but nothing helped me...

Comment: does it open OK in any other app?

Comment: Yes... I tried Google Chrome, Quick Look...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Preview > Preferences > Images` and select `Size on screen equals size on printout`.

[image]

Found this information at this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7252316) @ the Apple Discussions site. It seems to have helped other users with the same problem. I've never experienced it myself. Now I know what to do if it does happen!

Answer (score 0):

After set to **Size on screen equals size on printout** I had to scale my resolution to 1440 x 900 or 1680 x 1050 to make it work.

Steps: Go to System Preferences -> Displays -> select Scaled -> select one of 2 More Spaces on the right hand side of Default scale

Answer (score 0):

Update to OS X El Capitan v10.11.1.

```
Resolves an issue that caused JPEG images to appear as a gray or green box in Preview.
```

https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT205360